# Get a message my bot wrote

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want my bot to edit a message it wrote by appending some text to the original message. I don't want to store the message I sent so I would like to save the message identifier only and use it to get the message, append the text and edit the message but I can't find a way to get the message from telegram.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When posting your message to the telegram server, the server will return an object which contains the message, as well as the corresponding `message_id`.

*Possible response:*

```
{   
    "ok":true,
    "result": {
        "message_id": 123,
        "from": {"id": 98765, "first_name": "...", "username": "..."},
        "chat": {"id": 12345, "first_name": "...", "username": "...", "type": "private"},
        "date": 1475274917, "text": "Message Text"
    }
}
```

Later on you can edit the message with  [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext).

Comment: yes, but what I want to is to edit the message and append some characters to the original text. I don't want to store the original text in memory and I haven't found a way to get the original text or to make this kind of edition

Comment: You'll have to use [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) to edit the message.

Comment: but that method requires the whole text for the message. I want to append some text and I don't know how to retrieve the original text (or perform the appending)

Comment: You can't append to the message / get the text from telegram. You either need to store it yourself and append manually, or just write a new text.